# Issue in NSUserDefaults while retrieving data, value change from "0" to "1"

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am beginner in Objective C, while performing my Assignment I tried to save the object in NSUserDefaults
Object Created Successfully and after reopening of Object, the value changes of BOOL instance variable , from 0 to 1 of all objects.

Protocol's Method, which evaluates on Task Creation..

```
-(void)didAddTask:(Task *)task{
     [self.taskObjects addObject:task];
     NSMutableArray *arrayOfTaskObjects = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:TASK_OBJECTS_KEY] mutableCopy];
     NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfTaskObjects);
     if (!arrayOfTaskObjects) {
         arrayOfTaskObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }

     [arrayOfTaskObjects addObject:[self taskObjectAsAPropertyList:task]];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayOfTaskObjects forKey:TASK_OBJECTS_KEY];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The method to create Property List:

```
- (NSDictionary *)taskObjectAsAPropertyList:(Task *)taskObject{ 
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{TASK_TITLE:taskObject.taskTitle,
                               TASK_DESCRIPTION:taskObject.taskDescription,
                               TASK_DATE:taskObject.taskDate,
                               TASK_COMPLETION:@(taskObject.isTaskCompleted)};

    NSLog(@"Task Completion: %@", myDictionary[TASK_COMPLETION]);
    return myDictionary;
}
```

EDIT:
Code of Task Class:

```
@implementation Task

-(id)init{
    self = [self initWithData:nil];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary*)data{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.taskTitle = data[TASK_TITLE];
        self.taskDescription = data[TASK_DESCRIPTION];
        self.taskDate = data[TASK_DATE];
        self.isTaskCompleted = data[TASK_COMPLETION];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Edit 2:

```
NSMutableArray * demoArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:TASK_OBJECTS_KEY]mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"Retrievd Array From NSUserDefaults : %@", demoArray);
for(NSDictionary *dic in demoArray){

    Task *myTask = [[Task alloc]init];
    myTask.taskTitle = dic[TASK_TITLE];
    if (dic[TASK_COMPLETION]==0) {
        myTask.isTaskCompleted = NO;
    }
    else{
        myTask.isTaskCompleted = YES;
    }
    //myTask.isTaskCompleted = dic[TASK_COMPLETION];
    myTask.taskDescription = dic[TASK_DESCRIPTION];
    myTask.taskDate = dic[TASK_DATE];

    [self.taskObjects addObject:myTask];

}
```

Comment: show the code of setting values in task object .

Comment: @Jeyamahesan see now

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. it works like expected. check the code, whether your setting the boolean value as true somewhere else.

Comment: Make sure you check `[yourObject boolValue]` and not just `yourObject` if you check the booleans using an `if` statement.

Comment: @phi See my Edit.

Comment: You should use `myTask.isTaskCompleted = [dic[TASK_COMPLETION] boolValue];` instead of that if statement. Comparing `dic[TASK_COMPLETION]` with 0 will just compare the pointer (a NSNumber), not the value (a bool), so it will only be true if `dic[TASK_COMPLETION]` doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure that the Data you're going to save in NSUserDefaults, is the same that you entered, by Using NSLog statement.

Comment: I've checked, the data that is entered or the data that is received is correct. It is caused by some other issue, please see my code.

Comment: Ohh their is problem in your NSDictionary... Evaluate it step by step.